# Intelligent move block up and down in VS Code like in IntelliJ-based IDEs

Tags: visual-studio-code

There's the feature of moving a line/block up and down in VS Code, using single line steps. But IntelliJ-based IDEs have the ability to move blocks up (Ctrl+Shift+Up) and down (Ctrl+Shift+Down) and swap them with their logical counterpart, f.e. swap class methods with each other and things like that.

Is there a similar function in VS code?

Comment: very-very-marginally related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/63972